# How can I cook with worcestershire sauce in a pan without leaving an impossible to remove char on the pan?

Tags: cleaning, cookware

When I cook hamburgers inside, I do it in a pan on stove top. I usually use worcestershire sauce, but it seems that when I do it gets cooked onto the bottom of the pan. No amount of soaking makes it easier to clean off, I usually just have to use a copper wire pad and it's still rather difficult.

This is in an aluminum pan -- I think. It's not cast iron or non-stick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worcestershire sauce is fairly sweet, it's the sugar that's blackening. There's nothing you can do about it - if you add it to your pan it's going to char.

The solution is not to put it in the pan, but put it on afterwards or mix it in with the meat before making patties. You'll get a better result that way as well, you're destroying the flavor of the worcestershire sauce by charring it in the pan like that.

Comment: You can add water to the surface of the pan *before* the Worcestershire cooks down to the point of charring. That can be tricksy, but it's doable.